# Regexp's end of a word

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I cannot find in the python's RE module special symbol for the end of the word...

There is \b - beginning of a word, and \B - opposite of \b, which is match for the any symbol of the word except first... But why there is no just end of the word?

Am i missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `\b` is not just for beginning of the word, but also for the end of the word.

In regex, `\b` means word boundary. So `\b\w+\b` is a pattern for a single word.

Comment: Hm... really true. How strange. I cannot see the forest behind the trees :) Thanks i'm really missed something...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I misread your question, To my knowledge there is nothing to use to match the end of a word directly, however you should be able to use a pattern like `(?<=\w)\b` so you match any boundary with part of a word in front of it, you could further extend this with somthing like `(?<=\w{3})\b` to only match after words of 3 or more letters.

*Note this does not consume whatever is deliminating the word*

If I am trying to figure out regexes I find it is easiest to go and have a play with a tool like these

- http://re-try.appspot.com/
- http://regexpal.com/

Comment: I know this. But i need end of the **word**.

Comment: Thanks for the links, really helpfull answer now) because some time ago i've searched something like this for the python (i knew only rubular for ruby), but not found at those moment.